# Dereferencing a Function Pointer to Swap the Function

Tags: c++, c, pointers, function-pointers

I tried to redefine `malloc()` in order to use a custom allocator without modifying the code. Why doesn't the following code work? Is using `#define` the only left solution?

```
void *(*malloc_ptr)(size_t) = malloc;
*malloc_ptr = my_malloc;
```

Comment: `malloc` is not a function pointer, it's a function. It can decay into a function pointer.

Comment: @chris In that context it is a pointer I believe.

Comment: So, you initialize a pointer variable to `malloc` (after pointer-decay), and then assign something else. Why do you expect that to change the function whose address you assigned initially?

Comment: @xiver77: That's not what "it" means. "It" can *decay into* a function pointer, which means you can compute a prvalue from "it". But there is no stored object whose value you can change.

Comment: Why do you need custom allocator as `malloc`? Maybe there are better solutions. In C++ you can pass custom allocator to all STL types.

Comment: @Cyber: Hm. Why did you remove [tag:c++]???

Comment: @Deduplicator Because while this is valid C++ code, this is essentially only a C question. From the C++ tag: "C++ is a general-purpose programming language based on C. Use this tag for questions about code compiled with a C++ compiler, **regardless of whether the code could be valid in C, C#, Objective-C and other C based programming languages.**"

Comment: @Cyber: Where do you get the idea he's using a C compiler? Or not both?

Comment: The word "allocator" is confusing in a c++ context. I *guess* it has nothing to do with c++ allocators.

Comment: You are holding it wrong. You should *link* with a library that provides custom `malloc`. There are tons of such libraries out there. No need to redefine or recompile anything.

Comment: Your final question presupposes that "using #define" is a solution at all. Is it?

Comment: @n.m. This is a good answer, which actually answers the question, and doesn't just say why "it won't work". Maybe you should format it as a proper answer. Also, should the additional library be first or last to link? And how can one get rid of linker warnings on multiple functions?

Comment: This is certainly not a C++ question.  The solution for C++ is to not use malloc.

Comment: @WilliamPursell The title that I used, rather than `malloc()` is what my question is about.

Comment: @anatolyg A custom malloc library usuallly goes last in the link order. Normally there should be no multiple definition warnings at all, given how most linkers work.

Comment: I'm a mite confused.  It is my understanding that once an external name is resolved, (in an earlier listed library) that further instanced of that name in a later library would be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to reliably replace the memory allocation library, use [LD_PRELOAD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/426230/430766) and pass it your own implementation of malloc and free.

Clearly you *can* create your own variable called `malloc_ptr` and use that in all your functions, but be aware that other library functions will call the standard `malloc`.

Comment: I did the dereferencing regarding a function just as same as any other primitive type. It seems that is not the case though. What would be the problem if I simply #define malloc in the custom allocator's header file? instead of linking it during compilation.

Comment: @xiver77: That depends on your implementation. If you can *guarantee* only to call `malloc` / `free` from that particular compilation unit, it might be fine, and a `#define` would be easier. Otherwise you might get crashes and other undesired behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

There is no assignment operator for function designators.

If you want to assign one function pointer to another function pointer then you should write

```
malloc_ptr = my_malloc;
```

Comment: Operators aren't "for" anything. They're just part of the language grammar. Do you mean "assignment expression"?

Comment: @Kerrek SB What about defining an assignment operator FOR some class?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Defining things has nothing to do with that. An assignment operator is declared for all class types, and thus assignment expressions can be formed with class-type operands. (They may still be ill-formed if overload resolution fails or if the chosen overload is deleted, of course.)

Comment: @Kerrek SB You are wrong. Assignment operator is not defined for all entities in particularly for function designators